# C# Watermark an image without overlapping

Tags: c#

What i'm trying to do is write a string to an image without overlapping the image.  So i want to watermark an image putting the watermark (string) at the bottom without actually affecting the image or stretching the image out.  I already know how to turn a string into an image, just having problems accomplishing the watermark.

1) Write string to Image on bottom right hand side
2) don't stretch the original image
3) extend the bitmap a little bit to include watermark?

Does anybody have an example or an idea where to start?  If i don't make any sense i'll try to answer any questions.

Bitmap example:

here is the code I use to get the bitmap, how do I increase just the size by X like 20?

```
Bitmap original = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(coveted);
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(original);
```

And I guess the 2nd part is how do i determine the space that I need in order to write out a string to the very bottom right of the image, while fitting in the entire string...

@ROY:   This is the edit that i did.

This sorta works but the one watermark appears below the other.  if i could get them on the same line it would be perfect!

```
private static Bitmap WatermarkImage2(Bitmap bmpOriginal, String waterMark2)
    {
        using (Graphics gfxOriginal = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOriginal))
        {
            using (Font fntWatermark = new Font("Arial", 24, FontStyle.Regular))
            {
                SizeF szWatermark = gfxOriginal.MeasureString(waterMark2, fntWatermark, int.MaxValue);
                Bitmap bmpWatermarked2 = new Bitmap(bmpOriginal.Width, bmpOriginal.Height + (int)(szWatermark.Height * 2));
                using (Graphics gfxWatermarked = Graphics.FromImage(bmpWatermarked2))
                {
                    gfxWatermarked.Clear(Color.White);
                    gfxWatermarked.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpOriginal, 0, 0);
                    gfxWatermarked.DrawString(waterMark2, fntWatermark, Brushes.Black, 0, (bmpOriginal.Height + szWatermark.Height) - (szWatermark.Height / 2));
                }
                return bmpWatermarked2;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you specify if you use GDI (System.Drawing) or some other library?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "without overlapping" and "without actually affecting"?  Do you want to print the text to a section of the bitmap that doesn't have any important visual elements?  How would you define that?

Also, what is the difference between "don't stretch" and "extend a little bit"?  Do you want to add a black bar at the bottom of the image and put the text there?  That's not really watermarking.

Comment: well what is it, you know a black bar at the bottom is the right idea sorta, but i just want to extended the bitmap and write the stamps on the extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may work for you:

```
    private static Bitmap WatermarkImage(Bitmap bmpOriginal, String waterMarkLeft, String waterMarkRight)
    {
        using (Graphics gfxOriginal = Graphics.FromImage(bmpOriginal))
        {
            using (Font fntWatermark = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular))
            {                    
                SizeF szWatermarkLeft = gfxOriginal.MeasureString(waterMarkLeft, fntWatermark, int.MaxValue);
                SizeF szWatermarkRight = gfxOriginal.MeasureString(waterMarkRight, fntWatermark, int.MaxValue);

                float heightWatermark = szWatermarkLeft.Height > szWatermarkRight.Height ? szWatermarkLeft.Height : szWatermarkRight.Height;

                Bitmap bmpWatermarked = new Bitmap(bmpOriginal.Width, bmpOriginal.Height + (int)(heightWatermark * 2));

                using (Graphics gfxWatermarked = Graphics.FromImage(bmpWatermarked))
                {
                    gfxWatermarked.Clear(Color.White);
                    gfxWatermarked.DrawImageUnscaled(bmpOriginal, 0, 0);
                    gfxWatermarked.DrawString(waterMarkLeft, fntWatermark, Brushes.Black, 0, (bmpOriginal.Height + heightWatermark) - (szWatermarkLeft.Height / 2));
                    gfxWatermarked.DrawString(waterMarkRight, fntWatermark, Brushes.Black, (bmpOriginal.Width - szWatermarkRight.Width), (bmpOriginal.Height + heightWatermark) - (heightWatermark / 2));                        
                }

                return bmpWatermarked;                                        
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
using (Bitmap bmpWatermarked = WatermarkImage((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(@"c:\\test.bmp"), @"Copyright (C) A Corp."))
{
    bmpWatermarked.Save(@"c:\watermarked.bmp");
}
```

Combined with your code above:

```
Bitmap original = (Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(coveted); 
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(original); 
using (Bitmap bmpWatermarked = WatermarkImage(newImage, @"Copyleft (C) A Corp.", @"Copyright (C) B Corp."))
{
  bmpWatermarked.Save(@"c:\watermarked.bmp");
}
```

Comment: Looks good.  Just some notes: DrawImageUnscaled() doesn't actually work.  Use the overload that sets the image size.  And Image.Save() doesn't save in the BMP format by default, rename the file to .png

Comment: @roy  I cant get this part to compile using (Bitmap bmpWatermarked = WatermarkImage((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(newImage,true), @"Copyright (C) A Corp."))  it's telling me Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(string, bool)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Mike - You are passing in `newImage` which is a Bitmap object.  Instead you need to pass in the name of a file `@"c:\\test.bmp"`.  If you really want to pass in `newImage` then you don't need to call the function and can just pass `newImage` as the argument to WatermarkImage... Like this: `WatermarkImage(newImage, "@Copyright")`

Comment: @Roy wow that was awesome, defiently good, but i got a question for you since you seem to be a bitmap guru. This appears on the bottom right hand side exactly like i want, but what if i also want a watermark on the bottom left hand side at the same positioning?

Comment: @Mike - Simply copy the DrawString line and change the X coordinate to 0. `gfxWatermarked.DrawString(waterMark, fntWatermark, Brushes.Black, 0, (bmpOriginal.Height + szWatermark.Height) - (szWatermark.Height / 2));`

Comment: Awesome, i got you, but how do i define these as two differnt watermarks and put them on the same line?  Liek the text will be two differnt things

Comment: @roy do I have to make another private static Bitmap?

Comment: @Mike - I added the line to the first code sample in this post.

Comment: @roy i saw that, but i need to make two seperate watermarks, so in my edit i went and made another static bitmap, whats going on is the way i have it written out i have one stamp above the other, on opposite sides ofcourse, i need em on the same height.

Comment: @Mike - Copy and paste the first code sample in the this post.  It will do what you want.

Comment: @Mike - Or are you saying that you want a different font for each watermark?

Comment: @roy so use multiple private static Bitmap WatermarkImage(Bitmap bmpOriginal, String waterMark), but just change the one line to gfxWatermarked.DrawString(waterMark, fntWatermark, Brushes.Black, 0, (bmpOriginal.Height + szWatermark.Height) - (szWatermark.Height / 2));  right?

Comment: @Mike - Modified the first code sample in this post for different left/right text. Hopefully this suits your needs.

Comment: @Roy i see what you mean, but this line isnt compiling using (Bitmap bmpWatermarked = WatermarkImage(newImage, @"Copyleft (C) A Corp.", @"Copyright (C) B Corp."))   Puts out the error Error 1 No overload for method 'WatermarkImage' takes '3' arguments 
Also all the items on the new DrawString dont exist.

Comment: @Roy i'm just confused here i guess.  waterMarkLeft and waterMarkRight dont exists.  and in the line using (Bitmap bmpWatermarked = WatermarkImage(newImage, @"Copyleft (C) A Corp.", @"Copyright (C) B Corp."))  I cant get it to stop telling me it needs 3 arguements.

Comment: I know that waterMarkRight and waterMarkLeft are strings i have to define but how do I work that into the WatermarkImage(newImage, @"Copyleft (C) A Corp.", @"Copyright (C) B Corp."))

Comment: Forgive me for I have not awaken yet, you are the man!!!  All my quewstions was something stupid i was over looking

Comment: @ROY if i wanted to move the watermarks to the top of the page what would be the change?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is simply make the image larger than the original, and include your "watermark" at the bottom like an image footer.

What you need to do is to create a new Bitmap object that is larger than the original image (by the amount of the watermark).  Then use the Graphics DrawImageUnscaled method to draw the original image at 0,0 and then draw your Watermark Image at the bottom (or right, or wherever).

Comment: Thats what i'm guessing but how do i determine the bottom right coords and enough space to include my whole watermark.  I know to use MeasureString but i'm having a lot of time to peice it together

Comment: If you're having specific issues with MeasureString, then I would suggest posting the code you have.  Also be aware that MeasureString is not exactly... well... exact. It uses the average width of a font to determine certain metrics.

Comment: it has nothing to do with measurestring.  How do i extended a bitmap based on a string?